# Add taxonomy terms list to homepage

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

Please help me to add taxonomy terms from custom taxonomy into home page. I have no idea how to do this as I'm coming from WordPress. In WordPress it is easy as calling get_terms().
I have following file as my home page: `mytheme/templates/page--front.html.twig`

I have more than one taxonomy type and all of them are going to queried in the home page.

How to query the taxonomy terms?

**UPDATE:**

I have created a new region called `home_content` in my `theme.info.yml` and I have created a view(block) for getting the taxonomy terms, added it to region in back-end and display it as `{{page.home_content}}`. It works but I have few questions.

1. I have fields for logo and text in the taxonomy. I want to list them too.
2. I need to customize the html. How can I do that?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a view and list out taxonomy terms. Then display the view in front page.

Need to place view in `page--front.html.twig`.

Use [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module.

```
<dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}</dd>
```

For Block

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'block_1') }}
```

Comment: Please explain further. I have no experience with drupal.